# Guava equivalent for Apache commons.lang3 StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()

Tags: java, escaping, guava, apache-commons

Currently I'm using `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()` from Apache Commons, but this is marked as deprecated since 3.6 and the suggestion is to move to the `commons-text` package. Since I'm currently not depending on that, and don't feel the need to add another dependency for just this one package, I was looking into the escaping functionality that one of my other included libraries (Guava) provides.

However, I could not find an equivalent to the `escapeJava()` method. Since Guava seems to work a little differently, I was wondering if someone could point out how I could achieve the same result using Guava? (or using non-deprecated classes from `commons-lang3`)

Comment: Has anyone found a newer Java SE or Guava replacement for `StringEscapeUtils.escapeJava()`? Maybe Java 10 or newer versions of Guava include such a method…

Comment: @XDR I've not found anything else thus far. See my accepted answer for my final solution.

Comment: Thanks. I am not using any Apache commons libraries other than `escapeJava` from commons-test, so I’ll continue using that until either Java SE or Guava include a replacement. I heard Java SE will be adding some string escaping methods as a precursor to supporting raw strings, but I wasn’t sure if any of those methods were in Java already. Maybe they’ll be in Java 11…

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since I couldn't find any decent alternatives within guava, I gave it another go using the `StringUtils` class from `lang3`. I made a small utility function that escapes newlines and tab characters. Suggestions welcome, but this will do for now.

```
public static String escapeForLogs(String input) {
  return org.apache.commons.lang3.StringUtils.replaceEach(
    input,
    new String[] { "\r\n", "\r", "\n", "\t" },
    new String[] { "\\\\n", "\\\\n", "\\\\n", "\\\\t" }
  );
}
```

I run the following tests on it:

```
@Test
public void testEscapeForLogs() {
  assertEquals("without linebreaks/tabs stays the same", "lala", e scapeForLogs("lala"));
  assertEquals("empty string is fine", "", escapeForLogs(""));
  assertEquals("newline gets escaped", "\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\n"));
  assertEquals("two newlines", "\\\\n\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\n\n"));
  assertEquals("tab", "\\\\t", escapeForLogs("\t"));
  assertEquals("return carridge gets escaped", "\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\r"));
  assertEquals("return carridge+newline gets converted", "\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\r\n"));
  assertEquals("newline before cr+nl", "\\\\n\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\n\r\n"));
  assertEquals("2 cr+nl", "\\\\n\\\\n", escapeForLogs("\r\n\r\n"));
  assertEquals("some combination", "lala\\\\nlalala\\\\n\\\\nla\\\\tla", escapeForLogs("lala\nlalala\n\nla\tla"));
}
```

Comment: I suggest you update this useful answer with "descape" code... Should just be a reverse replace action...

Comment: I'll leave such a trivial thing as an exercise to the reader. Happy that you found my answer useful though.

Answer (score 2):

I don't see anything comparable. It really does look like the best option is to just add the dependency on `commons-text`.

However, if you're really against that, you could use Guava's `Escapers` and attempt to re-build the Java rules found in `StringEscapeUtils#ESCAPE_JAVA`. That seems like a worse approach however.

Comment: As stated in the question, I don't want to include another dependency for just this one method.

Comment: @MichielHaisma fair enough. I thought about doing what you did in your answer, but when it comes down to it, Apache libraries are built and tested by a lot of people. Rolling your own solution may work in this case. I&#39;ve just found that I&#39;ve been burned more times by custom solutions than I ever have been burned by additional dependencies. That said, maybe you have a JAR size requirement that I&#39;m unaware of, and it&#39;s for that reason you don&#39;t want to just use `commons-text`.